# Drag and drop mouse capture

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop, panel

I got a `Panel` and inside it some drag and drop operations of custom controls, when the dragging begins I do `panel.Capture = True;` for the panel to fire the proper events even when the user releases the left mouse button outside the panel bounds (e.g.: `panel_DragDrop`) but the `DragDrop` event isn't getting fired unless the left mouse button is released while the cursor is located within the bounds of the panel.

I thought `panel.Capture` would solve this but it's not doing any effect. Any ideas what am I missing here?

Edit: Ok I think I know what I have to do now. I think I had a misunderstanding of the DragDrop event. What I have in my application is dragging of controls inside the panel only ( think of it as moving blocks ), while the user is dragging a block and goes out of bounds, I auto scroll, if the cursor goes outside the panel, the `panel_DragDrop` never gets called and the placement of the block doesn't take place if the mouse gets released. I think my solution is this:
`Cursor.Clip = panelDiagram.RectangleToScreen(panelDiagram.ClientRectangle);`

This will make the cursor bound to the panel boundaries while dragging, so no way to take the cursor off bounds.

Sorry for any troubles

Answer (score 0):

I just created a little test project with just a form and a panel and this worked for me:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Form1
{

    public Form1()
    {
        DragDrop += DD;
        DragEnter += Panel1DragEnter;
        // This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Panel1.AllowDrop = true;
        AllowDrop = true;

    }

    private void Panel1DragEnter(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(sender, Panel1)) {
            Panel1.Capture = true;
        }

        if (Panel1.Capture) {
            if ((e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))) {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            } else {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
            Panel1.Capture = true;
        }

    }

    private void DD(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Panel1.Capture) {
            Interaction.MsgBox("dropped");
        }
        Panel1.Capture = false;
    }


}
```

Once you've dragged over the Panel, its been captured, but the Main Form still needs to have drag/drop handlers

Comment: Sorry but I can't make anything from your example. Try to have a `Panel` with a `Button` as a child. Enable D&D on the button, enable Capture on panel and drag the button outside the panel, will the panel1_DragDrop event fire? This is what I'm trying to achieve.